# Youtube iframe load many bytes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

I have a problem with my code. I have a list of many Bootstrap Panels collapsed. Each panel has an iFrame with a Youtube Video link this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="linkVideo collapsed" href="#10083" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
                <?php echo $title;?>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="10083" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="videoWrapper" style="display: none;">
                <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $faq['video']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I load my page and I have about 20/25 panels with 20/25 Video, I saw that it download 15/20 MB and is too slow. Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks ;)

**UPDATE**
I would dynamically initialise the iframes when the user expands them to include the content. Can you help me to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to load 25 videos at once? Couldn't you dynamically initialise the `iframes` when the user expands them to include the content?

Comment: Yes! I'd like to do this...but I don't know how...

Comment: No one can help me to solve this problem?